# Android Google maps polygon hourglass shape

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

I want to fill a polygon in Google maps, it works well when shape is convex. But when I create a shape like a hour glass, it cannot be filled, only stroke (see image attached). What's wrong here? How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Well, the bounds are crossing. Can you use two triangles?

Comment: no, I have to use polygon because the points are dynamic

Comment: Can you order them so you always draw in an outline (never cross back on yourself)?  E.g. TR, C, BR, BL, C (dupe), TL instead of TR, C, BL, BR, TL

Comment: Hmm, I'll try, thank you.